# Unable to install nvm using Docker

Tags: docker, nvm

I am working with AmazonLinux library to implement lambda functions using Node. For that I am following this link:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/resizing-images-with-amazon-cloudfront-lambdaedge-aws-cdn-blog/

When I am running DockerFile with commands:

```
FROM amazonlinux

WORKDIR /tmp

#install the dependencies
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ && yum -y install findutils

RUN touch ~/.bashrc && chmod +x ~/.bashrc

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash

RUN source ~/.bashrc && nvm install 6.10

WORKDIR /build
```

It is showing error at step 6 while installing:
[image: Docker error while insatlling node]

I am having following configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- node:10.6.0
- npm:6.1.0
- nvm: 0.30.2

I am getting this error, after adding tar library in docker image as suggested by  @Karol Samborki.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This definitely works, You forgot to add tar and gzip as it requires to extract nvm bundle.

```
FROM amazonlinux

WORKDIR /tmp

#install the dependencies
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ tar gzip findutils

RUN touch ~/.bashrc && chmod +x ~/.bashrc

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash

RUN source ~/.bashrc && nvm install 6.10

WORKDIR /build
```

Answer (score 2):

Your docker image is missing tar package. Change this line in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ && yum -y install findutils
```

to:

```
RUN yum -y install gcc-c++ findutils tar
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, it works but am getting this error.

Answer (score -6):

Don't install `nvm` in a Docker image.  Just use the right [node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) base image for the specific version of node.js you need, or if you really need to use some specific Linux distribution, install it in `/usr` or `/usr/local`.

`nvm` and other language-specific tools like it are useful when you need *multiple* language runtimes, but a Docker image only should do one thing and already has an isolated filesystem, so it's not the right tool here.